# How to set value of a form control which is inside a form array in Angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've a reactive form:

```
    this.leDetailsUpdateForm = new FormGroup({
      entityNameArray: new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          id: new FormControl(),
          entityName: new FormControl(),
          entityNameStartDate: new FormControl(), // <----- this i want to set
          entityNameEndDate: new FormControl(),
          entityNameStatus: new FormControl(),
          status: new FormControl(),
        }),
      ]),
    })
```

I'm trying to set it after some calculations as follows :

```
  setStartDates(e: any) {
    console.log(e);
    this.leDetailsUpdateForm.get('entityNameArray').get('entityNameStartDate').setValue(e)
  }
```

I'm not getting the required syntax on google. Please help.

Comment: It seems you can see it by debugging very easily !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access `FormArray` controls by index only so you can try something like

```
this.leDetailsUpdateForm.controls['entityNameArray'].controls[0].controls['entityNameStartDate'].setValue(e)
```

Comment: `this.leDetailsUpdateForm.get('entityNameArray.0.entityNameStartDate')`. "get" allow dot sintax. see that if you have a variable "index" you can use `this.leDetailsUpdateForm.get('entityNameArray.+index+'.entityNameStartDate')`

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
 setStartDates(e: any) {
    console.log(e);
    this.leDetailsUpdateForm['entityNameArray'].controls.forEach(d => {
        d['entityNameStartDate'].setValue(e);
    })
  }
```